# Small backup script in Python based on 7-Zip

Tags: python, file-system

Is this reliable?

While there are many backup programs out there, it is still hard to find free software that allows unattended differential backup on Windows. Completely rolling something from scratch is usually not the way to go and after some searching I found that 7-Zip can be utilized to achieve full and differential backups that are highly compressed.

My goal was to create a small script that can run unattended to create full backups every 30 days and in the intervals in between create differential backups to safe space. While the script runs nicely in a few tests, I am far from being a "pythonista" and would appreciate any feedback on code quality and reliability.

The program requires 7zip.exe in the path or current directory and requires two command line parameters, `--dest-dir destination_directory`, and the directories to be backed up given by `--input-dirs input_directory/ies`.

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import argparse
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

ARCHIVE_FILENAME_PATTERN = "py_backup_*_*.7z"
FULL_ARCHIVE_PREFIX = "py_backup_full_"
DIFF_ARCHIVE_PREFIX = "py_backup_diff_"
MAX_DAYS_BETWEEN_FULL = 30
MAX_DAYS_FOR_DIFF = 30

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def parse_date_in_filename(filename):
    import re
    date_in_name_pattern = '_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
    match = re.search(date_in_name_pattern, filename)
    if (match):
        date_object = datetime.strptime(match.group(0), '_%Y-%m-%d')
        return (True, date_object)
    else:
        # log that we could not match this filename
        return (False, None)


def get_valid_dir(parser, arg):
    if not os.path.isdir(arg):
        parser.error("The directory %s could not be found!" % arg)
    else:
        return arg


def archive_ok(file_path):
    """Tests whether the archive can be sucessfully decompressed with 7zip."""
    if (not os.path.isfile(file_path)):
        file_path = file_path + '.7z'

    test_command_string = u'7z.exe t '

    dest_path_string = file_path

    full_command = test_command_string + '\"' + dest_path_string + '\" '
    logger.debug("Testing archive with command: %s", full_command)
    encoded_form = full_command.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())

    return_value = subprocess.call(encoded_form, shell=False)

    if (return_value == 0):
        logger.info('Backup successful')
        return True
    else:
        logger.warn('Archive file test failed')
        return False


def run_backup(input_dirs, dest_dir, last_full_name, differential=False):
    """ Runs the actual backup using 7zip in archive or update mode."""
    current_date = date.today()

    input_dir_string = ' '.join("\"%s\"" % x for x in input_dirs)

    if differential:
        filename = DIFF_ARCHIVE_PREFIX  + str(current_date)

        diff_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
        dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, last_full_name)

        try:
            os.remove(diff_path + ".7z")
        except OSError:
            pass

        differential_command_string = u'7z.exe u '
        options = " -ms=off -mx=5 -t7z -u- -up0q3r2x2y2z0w2!"

        full_command = differential_command_string + '\"' + dest_path + '\" ' \
                       + input_dir_string + options + '\"' + diff_path + '\"'
    else:
        filename = FULL_ARCHIVE_PREFIX + str(current_date)

        dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
        archive_command_string = u"7z.exe a "

        full_command = archive_command_string + '\"' + dest_path + "\" " \
                       + input_dir_string

    logger.info("Executing command: %s", full_command)
    encoded_form = full_command.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    return_value = subprocess.call(encoded_form, shell=False)

    if (return_value == 0):
        logger.info('Backup successful')
    else:
        logger.warn('Something went wrong, return value of 7zip is %d', return_value)
        # 1 if directory to backup cannot be found
        # 2 means output file does already exist

    if (archive_ok(dest_path)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def search_backup_files(input_dirs, dest_dir):
    """Collects previous full and differential archives in the destination directory
       and sorts according to their creation date (encoded in file name)
    """
    import glob

    archives_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, ARCHIVE_FILENAME_PATTERN)
    archive_files = glob.glob(archives_path)
    logger.debug('Processing archive files: %s', (' '.join(archive_files)))

    full_backups = []
    diff_backups = []

    for path in archive_files:
        (directory, fname) = os.path.split(path)
        success, file_date = parse_date_in_filename(fname)
        if success:
            if (fname.startswith(FULL_ARCHIVE_PREFIX)):
                full_backups.append((file_date, fname))
            elif (fname.startswith(FULL_ARCHIVE_PREFIX)):
                diff_backups.append((file_date, fname))
            else:
                # skip file names that are not part of this set
                pass

    full_backups.sort()
    diff_backups.sort()
    return (full_backups, diff_backups)


def decide_backup(input_dirs, dest_dir, full_backups, diff_backups):
    """ Decides whether a full backup is required, i.e. the no full backup exists 
        or last full backup is too old. Otherwise a differential backup is sufficient.
    """
    differential = False
    # Consider a diff backup if a recent full backup is available
    if (len(full_backups) > 0):
        last_full_date = full_backups[-1][0]
        last_full_name = full_backups[-1][1]
        delta = datetime.today() - last_full_date
        if (delta < timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_BETWEEN_FULL)):
            logger.info("Only differential backup required, time delta is %s", str(delta))
            differential = True

    run_backup(input_dirs, dest_dir, last_full_name, differential)


def remove_old_diffs(dest_dir, full_backups, diff_backups):
    """ Removes differential backup files which are older than MAX_DAYS_FOR_DIFF."""
    for (file_date, filename) in diff_backups:
        delta = datetime.today() - file_date
        if (delta > timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_FOR_DIFF)):
            logger.info("Removing old diff-file: %s" %str(filename))
            os.remove(os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))


def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(u"-d", u"--dest-dir", help="destination directory",
                        required=True, type=lambda x: get_valid_dir(parser, x))
    parser.add_argument(u"-i", u'--input-dirs', help="directories to be backed up",
                        nargs='+', required=True, type=lambda x: get_valid_dir(parser, x))
    parser.add_argument(u"-r", u'--remove', 
                        help="removes differential backups older than 30 days", 
                        action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    handler = logging.FileHandler('py_backup.log', 'a', 'utf-8')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # file names can contain non-ascii characters but windows does not use utf-8
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764589/python-unicode-encoding
    dest_dir = args.dest_dir.decode('mbcs')
    input_dirs = [x.decode('mbcs') for x in args.input_dirs]

    (full_backups, diff_backups) = search_backup_files(input_dirs, dest_dir)
    decide_backup(input_dirs, dest_dir, full_backups, diff_backups)

    if (args.remove):
        remove_old_diffs(args.dest_dir, full_backups, diff_backups)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code Quality**

*1. PEP8/PyLint*:

Fix  http://pep8online.com/s/YnHEYUA5
I also suggest you to read these documents:

- [Python PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/bvm=bv.56146854,d.d2k)
- [Python docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

*2. Other improvements*

- You don't need to check that "a list is None": you can just use `if not sys.argv`. BTW, you never use *argv*.
- You don't need parentheses around operators in "if" statements. This is Python, not Java :)
- Remove imports from functions.
- All methods should be documented. Avoid comments that could be explained in the docstrings.
- Don't use "+" to concatenate strings. Use *.format()*.

**Code reliability.**

Code has no tests. How can it be reliable? 
Use [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html).

What if '7z.exe' is not in the SYS PATH?

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend starting with [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) (which is built into Python) and looking at third-party software like [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) only if the built-in facilities prove inadequate in some way.

Comment: I agree. If the OP is new to tests in general pytest is too much, but pytest is very powerful (it may include pep8, pylint, ...).

Comment: Thank you, these are all valid points. I am currently working on implementing the suggestions. While I agree with PEP8 the 80 character limit is difficult as it requires splitting up many strings which make the code sometimes less readable. I looked into testing frameworks and went for nose, which seems easy to work with and already helped.

Comment: Very good that you start with nose - excellent tool! 
Also, try to use tools like pep8/pylint - they are very important!
PS: Yeah, the limit of 80 characters is being discussed in the pep8 draft, in particular: http://bugs.python.org/issue18472#msg193785